# forming an object in a class to be called on by main. Java code

Tags: java, arrays, class, enumeration

I'm trying to create an array that mimics a 12-sided die. Using the for-each statement, it will work when i do it in a single class. However I have to call on it from another class. Is there a way i can create the object(4 12-sided dice) in a public class, using the for-each statement, then call on and roll the dice in main?

```
package gofirst;




public class DodecaDice {
   int[] a = new int[13];


   enum dieA{1, 8, 11, 14, 19, 22, 27, 30, 35, 38, 41, 48}
   for (DieA nextDieA: DieA.values()){
        a[0++]=nextDieA;
}




}
```

Comment: How does this even compile if your for loop is not in a method? And what the ... is a [0++] ? Anyway, that would be my suggestion: create a public method rollDie that returns the rolled value.

Comment: I dont know where to start explaining, you violate every single rule in the book ...

Comment: Have you tried making the `dieA` a separate class of it's own?

Comment: class Die, then create as many as u want

Comment: I know im a terrible programer at the moment. So thank you for your time. What i seem to be be getting from you guys is that i can not do a for statement to create an object in a separate class. Then call on the array in my main class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what it is you are trying to achieve, but if I was doing something like this I might start with a basic concept of a `Die` and it's core functionality...

```
public interface Die {
    public int getMinium();
    public int getMaximum();
    public int roll();
}
```

Then I would create an `abstract` version which filled out the most common, basic functionality, so I wouldn't need to repeat myself all the time...

```
public abstract class AbstractDie implements Die {

    private final int minimum;
    private final int maximum;

    public AbstractDie(int minimum, int maximum) {
        this.minimum= minimum;
        this.maximum = maximum;
    }

    @Override
    public int getMinimum() {
        return minimum;
    }

    @Override
    public int getMaximum() {
        return maximum;
    }

    @Override
    public int roll() {
        return getMinimum() + (int)(Math.random() * getMaximum());
    }

}
```

And then finally some implementations, for example...

```
public class TwelveSidedDie extends AbstractDie {

    public TwelveSidedDie() {
        super(1, 12);
    }

}
```

This would then allow me to use the class when ever I needed to, for example...

```
Die[] dice = new Die[] {new TwelveSidedDie(), new TwelveSidedDie(), new TwelveSidedDie(), new TwelveSidedDie()};
int sum = 0;
for (Die die : dice) {
    int roll = die.roll();
    System.out.println(roll);
    sum += roll;
}

System.out.println("Total: " + sum);
```

It should be noted that the above could also be achieved by using something like...

```
Die die = new TwelveSidedDie();
int rolls = 4;
for (int roll = 0; roll < rolls; roll++) {
    int result = die.roll();
    System.out.println(result);
    sum += result;
}

System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
```

Which leads to the ability to write a method that can simulate a number of `Die` rolls...

```
public static int[] diceRolls(Die die, int numberOfRolls) {

    int[] results = new int[numberOfRolls];
    for (int roll = 0; roll < numberOfRolls; roll++) {
        results[roll] = die.roll();
    }

    return results;

}
public static int sumDiceRolls(Die die, int numberOfRolls) {

    int[] results = diceRolls(die, numberOfRolls);
    int sum = 0;
    for (int result : results) {
        sum += result;
    }

    return sum;

}
```

Which would allow you to pass in any implementation of `Die` and have them rolled automatically as you needed...

For example...

Comment: Thank you, i already finished the program. However i did read all of your code to learn everything i could from it. I really appreciate all the help. Sometimes no amount of reading forms and text books can help as much as a direct example!

Comment: No, sometimes you just have to jump and completely screw it up ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your wanting but maybe its something like this. Is it required  for you to use 'for each'?

While I only show one dice you can make four of them in the main method... or maybe roll it four times.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Dice {

   private int[] a = {1, 8, 11, 14, 19, 22, 27, 30, 35, 38, 41, 48};

   public Dice() {
       //do nothing for now
   }

   public int roll() {
       Random rand = new Random();
       int  key = rand.nextInt(12) + 1;
       return a[key];
   }


   public static void main(String args[]) {
       Dice d = new Dice();
       System.out.println(d.roll());



   }

}
```

Comment: Wow that's far more elegant than the angle i was trying. I'm going to mess around with your code for a bit and see what i can learn from it. Thanks so much!